# Remove the `professional-education` tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The `professional education` tag has largely been used to ask career related questions. 11 out of 15 questions on the first page of results tagged with `professional education` is closed. The remaining 4 questions do not benefit much from the tag.

Should we remove the `professional education` tag?

Answer (score 8):

Definitely not. We have 179 questions tagged [professional-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional-education) and it has 4 synonyms in use as well.

This is actually a very useful tag, despite those closed questions you have seen on page 1.